# How to format widgets with row and column configuration?

Tags: python, tkinter, datagrid, widget, pack

I know this question has been asked previously, but I'm having trouble understanding it and figuring out how to implement it in my own program. I am extremely new to tkinter (just started today) and I'm unable to properly format my widgets. My goal is for the two leftmost widgets to be in a column together, and for the four widgets on the right to be centered with each other as well. Currently, I am unable to align the two widgets with the left edge, and my text widget gives an error when I try to format it using the grid. While researching these issues, I've come the the conclusion that I need to configure the rows and columns-- I'm just having a hard time understanding how exactly to do it to make it work in my code. To be more specific, I don't know where to put the configuration code or the amount of weight it needs to have, likely due to my limited knowledge in the subject.

I keep getting this error with my text box, if that helps:
`_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack`

Here is some of my code:

```
  def create_widget(self):

# name label and entry 
    self.name_label = Label(self,text='name')
    self.name_label.grid(row=0,column=0)
    self.name_entry = Entry(self)
    self.name_entry.grid(row=0,column=1)

# score label and entry 
    self.score_label = Label(self,text='score')
    self.score_label.grid(row=1,column=0)
    self.score_entry = Entry(self)
    self.score_entry.grid(row=1,column=1)

# button
    self.btn = Button(self,text='add',command=self.add)
    self.btn.grid(row=2,column=1)

# text box
    self.text = Text(root, width=40, height=12)
    self.text.pack()  

# prints to text box
  def add(self):
    name = self.name_entry.get()
    score = self.score_entry.get()
    self.text.insert(END,(f'name:{name} score:{score}\n'))

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x250")
root.mainloop()
```

Here is the current output:
[image]

And here is what I want the output to look like (without Jerry):
[image]

Let me know if any further information is necessary, and sorry if this question is a duplicate. Any further explanations, examples, or better methods would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use pack and grid on the same root widget.  So you should use grid the the text widget and add some padding and a columnspan to stretch it over multiple columns.

```
def create_widget(self):

    # name label and entry
    self.name_label = Label(self,text='name')
    self.name_label.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=(E))
    self.name_entry = Entry(self)
    self.name_entry.grid(row=0,column=1)

    # score label and entry
    self.score_label = Label(self,text='score')
    self.score_label.grid(row=1,column=0, sticky=(E))
    self.score_entry = Entry(self)
    self.score_entry.grid(row=1,column=1)

    # button
    self.btn = Button(self,text='add',command=self.add)
    self.btn.grid(row=2,column=1)

    # text box
    self.text = Text(self, width=40, height=12)
    self.text.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=4, sticky=(N,E), padx=10)

# prints to text box
def add(self):
    name = self.name_entry.get()
    score = self.score_entry.get()
    self.text.insert(END,(f'name:{name} score:{score}\n'))
```

[image]